# Are there slice compositions similar to layer compositions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, slices

Photoshop offers the feature of layer compositions. I can store different layer states within them and easily switch between them. In one, a certain layer is invisible and vice versa.

Yet once I slice up my PSD, I do not seem to be able to get something similar. My slices seem global to the window and cannot be tied up to a layer composition. This can mess up the save for web workflow.

I want to achieve a similar effect for slices as with layer compositions.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to use **History Snapshots**.

History Snapshots will actually allow you to save your slices in their different states. Personally, I don't use Layer Comps unless I'm presenting.

You might ask then, why would I ever use Layer Comps if History Snapshots essentially does the same thing? The important thing to know is that History Snapshots **does NOT** save with the document. Hopefully that will save you the hours it cost me in figuring it out. So will you have to go through each of the snapshots and Save to Web.
[image: History1]
[image]

Comment: Not being able to save is a huge downside. As I want to be able to export slices a few days afterwards in case part of the design or text change.

Comment: You can save them individually to separate files, just not as a part of a main file, unfortunately. It might be a source of pain that I undoubtedly share with you.