# How to trim a slice in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I know how to trim an image in Photoshop. (choose Image > Trim in Photoshop's menu)

Is there any method to trim a slice to get rid of extra transparent space?

Comment: You might want to look into this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I don't have the rep for a comment yet.

What I do is hide all other layers that aren't part of the slice. Then I add (or enable) a background layer with a different color from the edges of the slice (usually white, black or red). Then I zoom in as far as I can and use the color picker to find where the fade stops and the solid background color begins, and put a guide there. This gets tricky if you have an oddly-shaped graphic that you're trying to slice, where you have to find the most extreme pixel along any given edge. Then it's either 'slices from guides' or re-adjusting the edges of the slice to line up with the guides manually. Then turn off that background layer before I save that slice with transparency.

I suppose another method would be to slice your images roughly, not caring about the exact pixels, then saving the images with transparency. Re-open the images and trim transparent pixels and re-save.

I'd definitely be interested in finding a better way, as this is laborious, time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the background layer trick, are there any plugins or scripts can solve this problem?

Comment: Now I use imagemagick's trim operator to speed up the slicing. First, export the slice to png, then `convert slice.png -trim info:`, then adjust the X/Y/W/H of the slice and export again.

Comment: I create a photoshop script which uses imagemagick to trim the slice automatically. Github: https://github.com/clyfish/slicetrim

Comment: Nice looking script, I'll have to give it a try, cause I tend to do a LOT of slicing.