# How to save slices as separate images without using "Save for Web" in Photoshop cs6

Tags: cs6, slices

question from a non-graphic designer here.

All the examples I have seen at saving slices as separate images rely on using "Save for Web". What if I want to do the same when saving for printing?

Answer (score 6):

Crop the image before saving. Photoshop CS6+'s crop tool (in the toolbar, shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>) allows you to crop an image without actually removing the content you crop away. All you have to do is uncheck the 'Delete cropped pixels' box.

[image: delete cropped pixels box in Photoshop CS6]

When you're done saving (as), select the crop tool again and crop your next slice.

Comment: OK thanks, but can I save all my slices in one go? Using "Save for Web" you can save every slice as a separate image with only one click.

Comment: That's a good one, I don't know. I hope other answerers will help you better than I can.

Comment: If you are using anything under CS6 then this feature doesn't exist. You will need to crop the image, save it as a separate file, and then undo the crop from the starting file and save the image again. (To make sure you don't accidentally save the crop).

Comment: @cbp you might want to take a look at this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706

Answer (score 3):

If you have Illustrator, there's a simple File > Save Slices Command.
I was looking everywhere for a Photoshop feature like that, but can't find one. I ended up porting over to Illustrator and saving out from there.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! If you have any questions please let us know!

Answer (score 2):

Old question here but was first result on Google when I searched. Here is the option I used for **print** since *save for web will decrease resolution* and it seems there isn't a way to use slices to get higher resolution images

Use image assets, not slices: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html

It may seem a bit complex at first but once you try it out its very easy, and didn't require too much reworking of my sliced file to get it to work (but YMMV depending on what your file looks like)

In a nutshell - you make layer groups with their names in Photoshop as filenames and everything in that layer group will save out as the filename of the group every time you save the master Photoshop file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `save for web` even if you are saving for printing.

Just make the image size compatible with your printing needs before saving. 
So, make the image at whatever dpi/ppi and at size. Then slice and save for web.

It's not ideal, as PS will likely add some compression, but depending on the image you are working with, and the distance at which it is to be viewed, it just may work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Once the image is sliced, Go to export (save for web), then when you save it make sure it is on "save html and images" from the dropdown menu at the bottom. Photoshop with create a folder with your image saved as separate slices.

Comment: already said before, and the question specifies "without using 'save for web'"

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Photoshop 2020 and found this solution:

1. Go to File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)

That will bring up the dialog that allows you to choose photo settings. Then click SAVE and export your slices.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This question is about Photoshop CS6, not Photoshop CC 2020.  Many of these export options have changed since then. Also the OP wants an alternative to Save for Web, so this does not really answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

I use to use the slice feature all the time. I know this is a old post but it was near the top when I searched on google because I couldn't remember how to do this. You can actually do this using the slice tool in photoshop. Use it to select the things you want to slice and then click save for web. Granted it's not a one click deal but still very simple :)