# Export each folder as a jpg (or other) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Ive got about 15 folders (groups) in a `.psd` file each folder has multiple layers, together each folder makes one retouched and editted image, im aware of the `export layers to files` script, but is there a way to export each folder as a file ?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way is to run this script on the document:

```
for (var i = app.activeDocument.layerSets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].merge();
};
```

...and then use the export_layers_to_files.jsx script you already talked about.

This will take the top most Layer Groups, and merge them into a Layer named whatever the group was named. The second script will take those layers and export files however you want.

**NOTE: This will only merge TOP LEVEL GROUPS.** Groups within groups will not be treated separately.

The two scripts could be combined, but it depends on how often you need to run it.