# Photoshop Actions Save for Web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I am making a Photoshop file with a lot of slices some for iOS, some for Android and other formats. I need to create an action that saves only certain slices to the users desktop in a folder depending on what action they use.

I can do this and it works fine on my desktop but if I send the action to someone else they get an error due to the file location etc.

Is there a way to output these slices to somewhere so it works on both mac and PC and they are not computer relative?

Thanks Andy

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you're asking, mainly because the output folder locations will always need to be defined in the Action or Droplet. You can make the Action, but once another user loads them, they would need to re-define the output folders. You would need scripting to get around this.

Comment: [These could possibly serve as a better alternative](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706)

Answer (score 1):

Place at stop point at the save moment that allows the user to stipulate the location for saving.