# Is there a quick way of batch converting multiple files from JPG to PNG in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, batch-processing, file-format, image-format

I made a rookie error and accidentally saved about 20 images in Photoshop as `.jpg` files rather than `.png` files.

Is there a quick way I can convert all these files to a `.png` format at once rather than individually?

Comment: If your pngs are supposed to have transparent background, I wouldn't recommend conversion. I would probably look into other, more automatic ways of saving the images, rather than convert them.

Comment: I wouldn't convert the jpegs into PNGs regardless of transparency since the images will end up with less information than they could have, if saved as PNG straight from PS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up saving the PNGs straight from PS as you suggested. I don't want to risk ending up with less information.

Comment: [You might find these helpful.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by recording a custom Action of yourself:

1. Opening the file
2. Saving it as a `.png` file
3. Closing the file

Then you can automate this for the entire folder by going `File -> Automate -> Batch`. Choose the folder containing all the images and run your custom Action.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are about to commit another rookie error.

There is absolutely no advantage in converting a JPG file to PNG.

The JPG compression is now applied to your file, there is no way to "undo" that. The only thing you are going to have now is a bigger file size with the exact same quality as the JPG.

The only reason to do this is if you process again your image to add a transparency, or in the remote case your application can only use PNG, for example in the case of a Gaming engine. If that is not the case do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the process by making "action" in Photoshop. Its called "Batch Process".

Batch-process files:

1. Choose `File > Automate > Batch`
2. Specify the action you want to use to process files from the Set and Action pop-up menus.
3. Choose the files to process from the Source pop-up menu.
4. Set processing, saving, and file naming options.

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest importing all the images onto the same canvas and then 
 `File > Scripts > Export layers to file`.

Hoping this would help