# Photoshop: Save a part without cropping

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

when I need to save a part of an image as a new image in photoshop, I crop the picture, save-as, and undo the cropping. On huge files this is slow, and feels inefficient.

Is there a better way to tell Photoshop "save whatever you see in this rectangle as a new file"?

Comment: [These might help you out.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20705/are-there-slice-compositions-similar-to-layer-compositions/20706#20706)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no "Save Selection As" if that's what you're hoping for. The quickest way is probably to do:

1. <kbd>M</kbd> (rectangular marquee selection)
2. <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy merged)
3. <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (new file)
4. <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste)
5. <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (save)

Comment: This needs a side note. When you select an area of 100x100 pixels, but the left 50px are empty, *it will copy the right 50px*. It doesn't "save space" for empty pixels when you press CTRL+N. This can be both a good thing, and a bad thing, depending on what you want!

Comment: Not quite sure what @DirkvB means, but one thing I _love_ about this solution--you can highlight more than what is needed in the area (so as to not risk missing some elements), and when you Cmd+N it creates the _correct_ size and height *and* Cmd+V pasts exactly what you wanted. Thanks for this!

Comment: @thephatp exactly what you just said, but I explained the cause of it: Photoshop doesn't copy *empty* pixels.

Comment: This is great unless you want to copy vectored layers. Copy as merged gets rasterized, then resizing in the new document is 'flawed'. I'm looking for a way to save a section of the image at different sizes.

Comment: In regards to the edit someone attempted to make --- moving the mouse will never be as fast as a few keyboard strokes... @Tod post a new question then (and sorry I didn't see your comment sooner)

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies your selection to a single layer
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> makes a new document with the exact size of your cut
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes your flattened selection

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the `slice` tool <kbd>C</kbd>, hidden under the crop tool. Make a slice of the part you want to export, and then use `File > Save for Web...`. Downside is that all the other parts of the image will be saved as well, as separate image files.

Be warned that all of those slice image files will be saved into a directory named 'images'.

Comment: Resizing on export resizes the whole image not the slice you are exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Randy has the right idea using slices but it's even easier.  Say you have four images in a row.  Separate each with a vertical guide line and then, using the slice tool, click on "Slices From Guides" (in the slices toolbar).  Then save to web.  It will create four separate files with each slice.  You'll find them in that images folder.

Comment: Hello, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!